# Passing variable to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet, cout

I have a java class

```
public void doView(
        RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

//I need to pass the string variable over to my jsp
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
String sLang_Id = themeDisplay.getLanguageId();

include("/html/mypackage/view.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);

}
```

How would I read `sLang_Id` in my jsp

```
 <c:out value="${sLang_Id}" /> ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following before your call to the `include` method:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("sLang_Id", sLang_Id);
```

API available for reference at http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/index.html?javax/portlet/RenderRequest.html .

Comment: I get a ClassCastException `java.lang.NullPointerException04:27:42,076 ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.RenderResponseIm pl cannot be cast to javax.portlet.PortletRequest`

when I try to cast it as `((PortletRequest) renderResponse).setAttribute("sLang_Id", sLang_Id);`

Comment: Sorry!  Typo in answer, now corrected.  This is a function of the request, not the response - so set this on the renderRequest.

Comment: OK. Got it working now. 
In the mean time I thought why not try `renderResponse.setProperty("sLang_Id", sLang_Id);` but that din't work obviously.
Now why is that we need to setAttribute to `request`.And why not `response`. Because the java code is anyhow sending a response to the JSP?? Or did I get it wrong. When do we use `request` and when a `response`

Comment: Variables in JSPs, etc. have several different scopes - including request, session, and application.  As such, the variables are set against the request, not the response.  (Agreed, it can be a bit confusing at first.)