# Parameter value from URL is null

Tags: spring, liferay

There is a portlet in Liferay 6.1.0, where a jsp is redirected to another jsp with a parameter in the URL.

http://localhost:8081/web/guest/debitpayment?fishId=1467

I want to get the value of `fishId` with the code below, but it is null:

```
@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(PortletRequest request) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request));
    String fishId = httpServletRequest.getParameter("fishId");
    //fishId is null
    return super.formBackingObject(request);
}
```

Finally I tried this code to get the value from `queryString` and it returns the value. But I want to know why getting it from `httpServletRequest` is null.

```
@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(PortletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String fishId = getParameter(request,"fishId");
    //fishId is now 1476
    return super.formBackingObject(request);
}

public static String getParameter(PortletRequest portletRequest, String paramName) {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest);
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpRequest);
    String retval = portletRequest.getParameter(paramName);
    if (isNull(retval)) {
        retval = httpRequest.getParameter(paramName);
        if (isNull(retval)) {
            retval = httpServletRequest.getParameter(paramName);
            if (isNull(retval)) {
                retval = getParameterFromQueryString(httpServletRequest.getQueryString(), paramName);
                if (isNull(retval)) {
                    HttpServletRequest request = httpServletRequest;
                    try {
                        while (request != null) {
                            Method m = httpServletRequest.getClass().getMethod("getRequest", null);
                            request = (HttpServletRequest) m.invoke(request, null);
                            retval = request.getParameter(paramName);
                            if (Utility.isNotNull(retval))
                                break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

private static String getParameterFromQueryString(String queryString, String paramName) {
    String[] paramValues = queryString.split("&");
    for (String paramValue : paramValues) {
        String[] param = paramValue.split("=");
        if (param.length == 2 && param[0].equalsIgnoreCase("currentURL")) {
            String url = param[1];
            String[] url_splittedWithQuestionMark = url.split("%3F");// ?
                                                                        // mark
            if (url_splittedWithQuestionMark.length == 2) {
                String url_params = url_splittedWithQuestionMark[1];
                String[] url_paramValues = url_params.split("%26");// & mark
                for (String url_paramValue : url_paramValues) {
                    String[] one_paramValue = url_paramValue.split("%3D");
                    // =
                    // mark
                    if (one_paramValue.length == 2 && one_paramValue[0].equals(paramName))
                        return one_paramValue[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The URL you are providing looks like its missing the portlet identifier.  That may be causing the value not to get to the portlet.  It should look something like http : //localhost:8081/web/guest/debitpayment?p_p_id=myportlet_WAR_myportletportlet&fishId=1467.  P_p_id being the id of the portlet you want to receive the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem cause and the answer.
I used  *render-weight* config for this portlet in liferay-portlet.xml to change priority of its loading in a page. When I removed this config  everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I have not worked with Spring and Liferay. I have worked with MVCPortlet in liferay. So my attempt to answer is based on the MVCPortlet approach in Liferay. You maybe able to do something similar in Spring/Liferay as well.

To pass the values back and forth to various JSPs and to the custom Portlet class, we normally use render request or action request attributes. These request attributes can be set and retrieved in the `doView` and `processAction` methods of a custom Portlet class. I understand that this is recommended and proven approach. You maybe able to get the URL parameters working but you will find more examples/support and help using request attributes.

**Couple of examples are below of the API in the custom Portlet class:**

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws
   renderRequest.setAttribute("name", value);

public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws
    actionRequest.setAttribute("name", value);
```

In your JSP, you will be able to access it using the JSTL core and aui tags:

**JSP code example:**

```
<c:forEach items="${name}" var="varname">
<c:out value="${name}" />
<aui:option label="${name}" value="${name}" />
```

You can also refer to this post [Passing variable to jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410283/passing-variable-to-jsp)

Hope this helps!